# Jumpiness with iOS 11 Splash Screen using Cordova

Tags: cordova, splash-screen, ios11, xcode9

I'm having difficulty with the splash screen in iOS 11 with cordova.  I've created a Launch Screen.storyboard and put that name in for the "Launch Screen File" under the general tab.  The image in the story board file comes up but then a white screen appears and "jumps up" maybe 20 pixels with a black area at the bottom.  It is more pronounced on the X but exists to some degree with all iOS 11 devices.

I've tried including the splash screen plugin and not including it.  Including splash screen preferences in the config.xml file and not including them.

The rest of my app works fine, is converted to iOS 11 with viewport-fit=cover in the meta tag of the HTML files, the correct positioning of the status bar and css changes for the footer so that it doesn't collide with the new home button.

I've read several SO answers and blogs but no dice.  The problem is both in the simulator and on a device (iPhone 5S running iOS 11).  Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
  - Jon
```

Comment: Did you ever fix your problem?  I am seeing something similar for our Cordova app on the iPhone X.  I don't see a white screen and black area.  What I see is first the splash screen looks good at normal size for a second, and then stretches or gets very wide until the app loads.

Comment: I know this reply is late.  I did come up with an interim solution that kind of works.  It's been a while so this is what I think I did: 1) I added a blank white png 282px X 609px to the top level of the project (right below the project name in the Xcode Navigator.  2) I added a storyboard file that contains only that image, centered.  3) On the project's target page in Xcode, under the general tab, I do not use an asset catalog but set the just created storyboard as the launch screen file.  4) Then I add a reference to Default@2x~universal-anyany.png in my config file.